# Include foreign assembly into SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, .net-assembly

I encountered the following problem. When I try to add the assembly to SQL Server 2012 I get the following error:

> Assembly "iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere.v4.0" refers to an assembly "system.data.entity, version = 4.0.0.0, culture = neutral, publickeytoken = b77a5c561934e089.", Which is not in the current database. SQL Server attempted to locate and automatically load the specified assembly from the same location, where the referencing assembly, but the operation failed (reason: 2 (can not find the file specified.)). Load the specified assembly into the current database and try the request again.

After that I tried to add the assembly specified in the description and got the following:

> Assembly "system.runtime.serialization, version = 4.0.0.0, culture = neutral, publickeytoken = b77a5c561934e089." not found in the catalog SQL.
>   Attention! Detectable object structures assembly Microsoft. NET Framework "system.data.entity, version = 4.0.0.0, culture = neutral, publickeytoken = b77a5c561934e089, processorarchitecture = msil." not been fully tested in an environment running SQL Server. In the future, if you upgrade or service this assembly or the. NET Framework subroutine CLR integration may stop working. For more information, see the documentation for SQL Server. (. Net SqlClient Data Provider)

So I tried google it and found this related connect article:

https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/744584/unable-to-load-system-identitymodel-dll-assembly-into-sql-server-2012#details

Is it possible to do something about my problem?